# More than one sortable table

Tags: 7

I have two `tables` on my page and have added `sorting` to `headers` of both the `tables`. When I click on the `header` of the upper table, I **observe sorting in the table below** rather than in the table where I clicked the header.

Comment: Here is a discussion for multiple tables on single page.(https://www.drupal.org/node/1160840)